# ld: 24 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64?

Tags: c++, duplicates, clion

I am writing a C++ project
Here are my files:

- `main.cpp`
- `define.h`
- `Solver.cpp`
- `Fileparser.cpp`
- `Puzzle.cpp`

I declare every function and variables in `define.h`.

In the other four files, I `#include "define.h"`

When I run this project, I got this error:

```
duplicate symbol '_Way' in:
CMakeFiles/main.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/fileparser.cpp.o
....
duplicate symbol '_variable' in:
CMakeFiles/main.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/solver.cpp.o
ld: 24 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

but I only declared variable Way and variable in `define.h` which is like:

```
int Way;
int *variable;
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. Hard to say what exactly, because you didn't show us the code. Please read: [mcve]

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for your advice, I have edited it,hope it will be more clear :)

Answer (score 2):

If in your `define.h` you have something like `int Way;`, then in every `.cpp` file that includes this `define.h`, the variable is **defined**.
At link, many definitions of this variable exist.

If you want to **declare** this global variable (I don't encourage the usage of global variables), you need to write `extern int Way;` (the declaration) in your `define.h` and then `int Way;` (the definition) in **only one** `.cpp` file (translation unit).

When we deal with functions, the distinction between **declaration** and **definition** is obvious: it relies on `;` vs `{...}` after the *prototype* of the function.
When it comes to global variables, the `extern` keywords is needed to express this distinction (you can also use `extern` before function declaration, but it does not bring anything more).

As a reminder, a **declaration** is a kind of promise we make to the compiler « I swear this variable, function... exists somewhere then it is correct to attempt to use it » ; on the other hand, a **definition** is like « here is the only instance of the variable, function... many know about ».

Note that in **C** these multiple **definitions** of the same global variables (without `extern`) can be accepted because of the *common* section.
This section collects the global variables with the same name in multiple translation units and merges them; this is a bad practice because your are not even certain they have the same type in different translation units.
Using `-fno-common` in `gcc` prevents this (in recent versions of `gcc` [this is now implicit](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html#c)) from being allowed.
In **C++** it's like `-fno-common` was implicit; thus the link error you observe.

Comment: i have got your idea. But if I want to use variable in many files,what should I do?

Comment: btw,when I write in C, i found this problem no longer exit, how to explain this?

Comment: @JustinHarold « what should I do? » --> use `extern` as explained in the answer. I edited the answer about C vs C++ when it comes to the *common* section.